# unning opencv_traincascade, The first stage 0 has takentoo long

Tags: opencv

Running opencv_traincascade, The first stage 0 has taken already 14h and is not progressing. Any ideas?, am I using too many images?. 
I had 245 positives cropped to -w 100 -h 75, then had 4064 negatives. I created 20 samples for each
positive using create_samples app, then each .vec (245 in total) was merged to create a single .vec file, then ran the train_cascade with this last merged .vec.

thank you in advance.

Here is the command:

opencv_traincascade.exe -data Trained_Classifier-vec SamplesCollectVec_Merge.vec
-bg negatives.txt -numStages 20 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -numPos 2450 
-numNeg 4064 -w 100 -h 75 -mode ALL -precalcValBufSize 1024 -precalcIdxBufSize 1024

Here is a screen capture:
numPos: 2450
numNeg: 4064
numStages: 20
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 1024
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 1024
stageType: BOOST
featureType: HAAR
sampleWidth: 100
sampleHeight: 75
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.999
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100
mode: ALL

===== TRAINING 0-stage =====

Comment: Possible duplicate of [opencv\_traincascade always gets stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552167/opencv-traincascade-always-gets-stuck)

Answer (score 0):

The number of samples you are using seems fine.

I suspect your sample resolution is too high.  Try subsampling using opencv_createsamples:  `opencv_createsamples.exe -vec SamplesCollectVec_Merge.vec -bg bg.txt -num 245 -w 20 -h 15`